# QGIS geoprocessing scripts, default values for field names

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, default-value

In QGIS geoprocessing scripts, default values must be provided for input numbers and strings, according to http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#creating-scripts-and-running-them-from-the-toolbox like:

```
##mynumer=number 3.1415329
```

Since I often have to process layers with all the same field names (unfortunately not assurable in any case), I would like to pass a default value for a field name to the geoprocessing script, following a logic like 'take the default field name if it exists in the layer referred to, otherwise let the user select one'.

Is this possible somehow, perhaps with a bit of python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how to modify the interface of such scripts but you could use an example script like the following where the `Enter_field` parameter has a default string of `ID` and if a field name matches this, it prints this field name otherwise it will print the one that is selected in the `Or_select_field` parameter:

```
##Example=name
##Input_layer=vector
##Enter_field_name=string ID
##Or_select_field=field Input_layer

layer = processing.getObject(Input_layer) 
field_names = [ field.name() for field in layer.pendingFields() ]

if Enter_field_name in field_names:
    print Enter_field_name
else:
    print Or_select_field
```

You would replace the print statements and use your code for both `if`, `else` statements while changing the `Enter_field` and `Or_select_field` parameters accordingly.

---

*Side note:*

*If that number is supposed to be pi, should it be `3.1415926`? :)*

Comment: Funny coincedence... I've accidentally typing something only ~6*10**-5 away from pi!!!

Comment: But to be serious: Besides blowing up the gui when having some more  fields, very helpful bit of python!

Comment: @JochenSchwarze - Glad it was helpful! Yes, the GUI can get a bit messy if you use a lot of parameters. Always wondered if the GUI can be modified within the script itself... =)